# How to enable OS AppTheme Dark/Light in Run time in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am following [Respond to system theme change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes) to respond to OS theme in xamarin form app. The app supports both Dark and Light themes with `AppThemeBinding`. I am not using any custom themes. I am following OS themes only. So I have a `Switch` which the user would prefer to enable Dark Mode (same as OS). The link suggests the following code to enable specified Mode (e.g Dark Mode).

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;
```

The above code does nothing, but if I write the above code in App.cs after `InitializeComponent()` The app changes to `Dark Mode`.

I Then realized to restart the `MainActivity` in Android which I did with the help of Dependency.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidThemeChanged))]
    public class AndroidThemeChanged : ITheme
        {
            public void OnThemeChanged()
            {
                var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
                var intent = GetLauncherActivity();
                activity.Finish();
                activity.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            public static Intent GetLauncherActivity()
            {
                var packageName = AndroidApp.Context.PackageName;
                return AndroidApp.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            }
        }
```

and Calling it

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
   DependencyService.Get<ITheme>().OnThemeChanged();
```

Is there any way to update application theme irrespective of `OS theme` (Dark/Light) without restarting the `MainActivity`?

Comment: Have you tried with getting the current theme on start-up with `OSAppTheme currentTheme = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#detect-the-current-system-theme

Comment: Well, That would give me the current theme applied. If I apply OS theme in App.cs at application startup, the app accepts that theme. However, what I want is to change OS theme in my app at run time. (e.g) The OS theme is Light, but the user wants to enable OS Dark theme so I have to apply Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark; (This doesn't change my app theme on the spot unless I restart my app)

Comment: Please update your question, because your last sentence is a bit confusing - `to update application to follow the OS theme`. What you want is not to change "OS" theme, but to have an independent app theme, which doesn't track the configuration of OS theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I guess I was wrong. The code in my question works as expected. I don't need to have that Android Service to restart activity.
Calling below from any where changes the theme to Dark irrespective of OS theme.

Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: I tried this, but for Android the app will not load my drawable-night-* images. Does that work for you? Any tips?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you don't have to restart the MainActivity. As per the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#react-to-theme-changes) we can react to the theme changes using the `Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged` event.

> Please make sure to follow the AppThemeBinding markup extension as per the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#appthemebinding-markup-extension).

Try the below code.

```
Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += Current_RequestedThemeChanged;

private void Current_RequestedThemeChanged(object sender, AppThemeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RequestedTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark)
        Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;
    else
        Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: For this I have to explicity define two themes Dark/Light, However, if you see AppThemeBinding this doesn't require explicity definition of themes. If you write Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark; in App.cs (application startup) your app will change to Dark Mode irrespective of explicit theming. Please see section "Set the current user theme" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes

Comment: My bad. I just modified the answer. Try this one. I hope it helps. If not try to upload a demo on what you are trying.

Comment: Should use 'Application.Current.RequestedTheme' instead of 'e.RequestedTheme'